# How to publish an extension to the new (Chromium based) Edge store?

Tags: microsoft-edge, publish, microsoft-edge-extension

What is the procedure to publish an extension to the new Edge insider addons store?
https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/insider-addons/category/EdgeExtensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting today (December 16th 2019), it's possible to submit extensions through partner portal : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099798

Initial developer documentation is available here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2112850, and there is more coming soon.

Additional questions about the extension submission process can be sent to Microsoft Edge Addons Developer Support : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099580

Official announcement: https://blogs.windows.com/blog/2019/12/16/get-started-extensions-addons-microsoft-edge-chromium/